# DataFrame from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Sorry, if it is a duplicate, but I didn't find the solution in internet...

I have some dictionary

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Now I want to construct pandas DF with the columns names corresponding to key and values corresponding to values. Actually it should be Df with only one row.

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

At the other topic I found only solutions, where both - keys and values are columns in the new DF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some caveats here, if you just pass the dict to the DataFrame constructor then it will raise an error:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index

To get around that you can pass an index which will work:

```
In [139]:

temp = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
pd.DataFrame(temp, index=[0])
Out[139]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Ideally your values should be iterable, so a list or array like:

```
In [141]:

temp = {'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]}
pd.DataFrame(temp)
Out[141]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Thanks to @joris for pointing out that if you wrap the dict in a list then you don't have to pass an index to the constructor:

```
In [142]:

temp = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
pd.DataFrame([temp])
Out[142]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Comment: Instead of providing `index=[0]`, you can also put the dict in a list: `pd.DataFrame([temp])`. This also scales more easily if you have multiple of this dicts each containing one row.

Comment: @joris, that is a nice trick never thought about that method before

Comment: it is like the 'records' option in `to_dict`

Comment: @joris I confess I have never used `to_dict` I'll take a look thanks

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise, just I need only create new DF.

Answer (score 1):

For flexibility, you can also use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` with `orient='index'`. This works whether your dictionary values are scalars or lists.

Note the final transpose step, which can be performed via `df.T` or `df.transpose()`.

```
temp1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
temp2 = {'a': [1, 2], 'b':[2, 3], 'c':[3, 4]}

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp1, orient='index').T)

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp2, orient='index').T)

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```